# Why Are AsObservable and AsEnumerable Implemented Differently?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, system.reactive

The implementation of `Enumerable.AsEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)` simply returns `source`. However `Observable.AsObservable<T>(this IObservable<T> source)` returns an `AnonymousObservable<T>` subscribing to the source rather than simply returning the source.

I understand these methods are really useful for changing the monad within a single query (going from IQueryable => IEnumerable). So why do the implementations differ?

The `Observable` version is more defensive, in that you can't cast it to some known type (if it original were implemented as a `Subject<T>` you'd never be able to cast it as such). So why does the `Enumerable` version not do something similar? If my underlying type is a `List<T>` but expose it as `IEnumerable<T>` through `AsEnumerable`, it will be possible to cast back to a `List<T>`.

Please note that this isn't a question on how to expose `IEnumerable<T>` without being able to cast to the underlying, but why the implementations between `Enumerable` and `Observable` are semantically different.

Comment: Source code for `AsEnumerable`: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cshttps://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs I couldn't find one for `AsObservable`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your question is answered by the documentation, which I encourage you to read when you have such questions.

The purpose of AsEnumerable is to hint to the compiler "please stop using IQueryable and start treating this as an in-memory collection".

As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) states:

> The `AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method has no effect other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that implements `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` itself. `AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` can be used to choose between query implementations when a sequence implements `IEnumerable<T>` but also has a different set of public query methods available.

If you want to hide the implementation of an underlying sequence, use `sequence.Select(x=>x)` or `ToList` or `ToArray` if you don't care that you're making a mutable sequence.

The purpose of AsObservable is to hide the implementation of the underlying collection. As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211761%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) says:

> `Observable.AsObservable<TSource>` ... Hides the identity of an observable sequence.

Since the two methods have completely different purposes, they have completely different implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I recently watched a video on Channel 9 with Bart De Smet where he explained IQbservable and it's relation to IObservable. From the way he explained it, it sounded like AsObservable was the analog to AsEnumerable in that any observable actions would happen locally rather than remotely. Did I totally misunderstand this (probably...), or is that simply another use for AsObservable?

Comment: I don'tknow. I recommend asking Bart de Smet that question.

Comment: Okay thanks, probably a good idea. I did read the documentation before asking - but the confusion was as a result of the video mentioned in my previous comment

Answer (score 11):

You're right about the relationship between AsEnumerable and AsObservable wrt the aspect of switching from expression tree based queries to in-memory queries.

At the same time, exposing an Rx sequence based on a Subject<T> is very common, and we needed a way to hide it (otherwise the user could cast to IObservable<T> and inject elements).

A long while ago in the history of Rx pre-releases, we did have a separate Hide method, which was merely a Select(x => x) alias. We never quite liked it and decided to have a place where we deviated from the LINQ to Objects precise mirrorring, and made AsObservable play the role of Hide, also based on users who believed this was what it did to begin with.

Notice though, we do have an extension method called AsObservable on IQbservable<T> as well. That one does simply what AsEnumerable does too: it acts as the hint to the compiler to forget about the expression tree based querying mode and switch to in-memory queries.

Comment: Thanks for checking out this old question Bart, your answer provides some interesting info.